# Cycle in a singly linked list

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to find if a singly linked list has a cycle or not, so I am implementing the slow and fast pointer approach. In which we make one pointer fast and the other one slow and see if they meet at any point. But I am not able to understand how to compare these 2 pointers.

here's is one implementation using this approach

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.next = None

class Solution:
    def hasCycle(self, head: ListNode) -> bool:
        if head is None:
            return False
        slow = head
        fast = head.next
        while slow != fast:                        # This the line on which I am having trouble
            if fast is None or fast.next is None:
                return False
            slow = slow.next
            fast = fast.next.next
        return True
```

Say we have the following linked list and let's say the slow pointer is at the first `3` and fast at the second one :

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 3 -> 5
          ^         |
          |         |
          +---------+
```

Now here what when we say `if slow == fast` what does it mean?

I think slow here is represented as `3 -> 3 -> 5 ..` and fast as `3 -> 5 ..` so what are we comparing here, the pointer location in memory ?

In case of string when we say `s= "abc"` what we mean is s has a pointer to the starting location of string and at we go till we hit a null pointer which represents a string. But what does this circular linked list mean?

Comment: It depends on the `__eq__` method for the class, the default compares memory locations, i.e. "are these the same object"? Python doesn't have pointers. `s= "abc"` makes a string object. The null terminator is a C construct which is an implementation detail specific to CPython but has no bearing on Python.

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks this makes sense :)